# 550 2607:f8b0:4864:20::132 is not allowed to send mail from

Tags: email, spf

When I try to send an email I get the following error:

> 550 2607:f8b0:4864:20::132 is not allowed to send mail from
>   mydomain.com. Please see the SPF record, with scope mfrom, identity
>   myuser@mydomain.com, and ip 2607:f8b0:4864:20::132

I use gmail to send mails from myuser@mydomain.com

This is how all the MX and TXT records I have at Cloudflare:

[image]
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please do not use commercial websites (such as mydomain.com) as placeholder examples. Generally, it's best to give your real address. If you must elide it, use a standard placeholder from [RFC 2606](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606#section-3).

Comment: This question is different and the answer is specific to gmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first look up what a [Sender Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) is. It is up to you to decide, which servers may send e-mail on behalf of your domain, all other servers will be suspicious (usually spammers).

If you want to send e-mail only from GMail, you need to find and copy GMail's policy:

```
piotr@bialykiel:~$ dig gmail.com TXT +short
"globalsign-smime-dv=CDYX+XFHUw2wml6/Gb8+59BsH31KzUr6c1l2BPvqKX8="
"v=spf1 redirect=_spf.google.com"
piotr@bialykiel:~$ dig _spf.google.com TXT +short
"v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com include:_netblocks2.google.com include:_netblocks3.google.com ~all"
```

So probably what you want is a TXT record containing:

```
"v=spf1 include=_spf.google.com ~all"
```

It means: we usually send from these IP addresses (you can find a list digging further the includes), but we **may** use another IP address.

E-mail providers usually explain what records are needed. You'll find [Google's explanation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786) on their help pages.

Comment: Just an FYI, using `-all` at the end of your SPF record is more secure, but you must add every domain/server that could send email for your domain. For example, ours needed an `include` for Mailgun, Mailchimp, and Gmail.